# losing scope in controller via factory

Tags: angularjs, service, scope, factory, directive

I am having the following problem where I lose the scope variable (movie)  in the controller (using a factory method). If I set the variable outside the function, things work (the LOOL movie). Can someone help please ?

```
 film.getMovie().then(function (response) {
  $scope.movie = response;
  console.log(response);
}, function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0VmiTSRqikaB37aHD8l1?p=preview) of the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/OlQaLXO1GMvMMDJnaQul?p=preview

Use a watch in the directive to know when the value is changed

```
  app.directive('info', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      scope: {
          film: '='
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('film',function(){

          console.log("Scope: " , scope);
          console.log("Film:", scope.film); // GRRRRRR
        })
      }
  };
});
```